# How to convert betwee number of minutes to hh:mm format in obj-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to convert betwee number of minutes to hh:mm format in obj-c?
For example, 65 minutes = 01:05 ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you literally want to format minutes as hh:mm, then this is a trivial math + string formatting problem.

An inline conversion would look like:

`[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%02d:%02d", minutes / 60, minutes % 60]`